# What is the casting strength limit of an enchanted item?

Tags: magic-items, dresden-files, crafting

In the DFRPG book *Your Story*, under "Enchanted Items" on page 280 it states that:

> Subsequent enchanted item slots allow you to:
>
> - Create a new enchanted item with a new effect
> - Add +1 to the strength of the default effect on an existing enchanted item
> - Add 2 to the uses per session for an existing enchanted item
>
> Regardless, **an item’s casting strength after
> all bonuses are totaled should never exceed
> two times the crafter’s Lore rating**

Regarding the section in bold, I'm unclear as to exactly what this means.
I see four possible interpretations:

1. The effect strength of a single enchanted item cannot exceed 2×Lore.
2. The effect strength + the number of uses per session of a single enchanted item cannot exceed 2×Lore.
3. The combined effect strengths of all enchanted items cannot exceed 2×Lore.
4. The combined effect strengths of all enchanted items + the combined uses per session of all enchanted items cannot exceed 2×Lore.

If anyone could inform me which is the correct interpretation, or if the answer is something that I have not considered, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lore limit rule is only for "casting" strength of enchanted item effect and it is only in effect on item creation time.

So basically if you a wizard with +3 Lore you can have enchanted item with +6 effect maximum. This rule doesn't govern number of uses or total number of enchanted items wizard can have (total number of Enchanted Items limited by Enchanted Items slots and number of uses is depends on mechanic of item creation).

And to make it clearly simple this rule states after you have totaled all your strength effect bonuses (from all sources: specialization, sponsor help, focus items) strength effect of enchanted item can not be more than Lore x 2.

Comment: Aardvark is correct. As the excerpt says it's "an item" and "casting strength".